# How do I decorrupt "git credential-'store"?

Tags: git, credentials

After generating a new Repository and adding an README, I try to push it to Git, but the following error occurs.

```
git credential-'store get: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
git credential-'store get: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
git credential-'store get: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
git credential-'store get: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

While global an local credentials are correct.

How Do I correct this error?

Where Do I find that file, that causes it?

Comment: Look at your Git configuration files (`git config --global --edit` and/or `git config --edit`). You have probably set `credential.helper` to something that includes this single quote. Be sure you know how to use the editor that `git config --edit` will invoke! There's a bit of a bootstrapping problem here if you want to configure `core.editor` to use an editor that you like when you aren't able to use `git config --edit` to invoke the editor that you like. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the file containing the offending bit of config by running `git config --list --show-origin`.

Just edit the file to remove the bad line of config and you should be good

Comment: Thank you very much. Finally the problem is solved!